# How to avoid full thread dump on shutdown?

Tags: java, jvm, tomcat8

I'm running a Tomcat 8.5 and each time I shutdown the tomcat via the control scripts, it dumps it's threads:

```
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.232-b09 mixed mode):

"Framework stop" #101 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fb540004800 nid=0x1a05 runnable [0x00007fa8a10ed000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
...
JNI global references: 1348

Heap
 garbage-first heap   total 13041664K, used 3910741K [0x00007fb5e7800000, 0x00007fb5e80031c0, 0x00007fbe2c000000)
  region size 8192K, 1 young (8192K), 0 survivors (0K)
 Metaspace       used 94108K, capacity 99079K, committed 99244K, reserved 100352K
```

After that it takes ~2 minutes to get to the next log message:

```
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

It seems that the dumping of all threads takes quite a while, which I really don't need during a regular shutdown.

We are utilizing OpenJDK 11 on EC2 Linux instance.
The control script is utilizing the `catalina.sh` which itself seems to use the shutdown port.

`catalina.sh stop` is the command issued by the scripts.

The same behavior happens when I execute `kill -3` on the Tomcat instance.
`kill -15` does not show this behavior.

Is there a possibility to deactivate this behavior, either in the Tomcat configuration or the JVM parameters?

Comment: *"... via the control script"* - Please be specific.  Which control script?  What arguments?  Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I added this information.

Comment: Looks like the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Apparently, the thread dump is not a *reason*, but a *consequence* of the fact that the application does not shutdown in time. `catalina.sh` purposely [makes a thread dump](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/cb5eaa3925bb4649a74a3872a9fda76fc9d102b1/bin/catalina.sh#L587) when stop operation takes long. This is exactly for investigation of shutdown issues. Look into the thread dump instead of trying to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks @apangin, that's propably the issue there. I was not aware of the timeout there.

Comment: Producing heapdump on `kill -3` is by design. It seems you can disable signal handling with the `-Xrs` option but it can have performance implications: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951812/why-does-xrs-reduce-performance

Comment: @apangin: Do you want to post your comment as an answer? As this was the information clostest to a solution, I'd be happy to select this as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the thread dump is not a *reason*, but a *consequence* of the fact that the application does not shutdown in time.

`catalina.sh` purposely [makes a thread dump](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/cb5eaa3925bb4649a74a3872a9fda76fc9d102b1/bin/catalina.sh#L587) when stop operation takes long. This is exactly for investigation of shutdown issues. I'd suggest to look into the thread dump instead of trying to avoid it.